# Python - BeautifulSoup - How to do online data parsing

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpWPJ.jpg) and I'm able to fetch the brand tag and the category tag, but I can't seem to be able to parse the price tag. Also, some of the shoes are on sale, and the HTML code seems to be different for those.

Any ideas on how to improve the parsing code?

Here's what I have so far.

```
url="https://www.sportsexperts.ca/fr-CA/femmes/chaussures?pagesize=451"

contenu = requests.get(url)
page = BeautifulSoup(contenu.text,"html.parser")

for urlchaussure in urldeschaussures:
chaussure =[]
try:
    url2 = urlchaussure.a["href"]
    url2 = "https://www.sportsexperts.ca" + url2

    contenu2 = requests.get(url2)
    page2 = BeautifulSoup(contenu2.text,"html.parser")

    prix = page2.find(class_ ="price").find_next("span").text
    print(prix)

except:
    print("rien ici")
```

[here's the link to the website](https://www.sportsexperts.ca/fr-CA/femmes/chaussures)

Comment: Please [dont post images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9348376). Put the code in the post itself.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! edited

Comment: I don't see any class called `price`, I think you should be [searching for `product-tile-price`](https://i.imgur.com/b0m0SoH.png)

Comment: Well if you go on each product, which is what I need to do, you can see the [class called price](https://imgur.com/fzIx5gf). I need to parse the data from each shoe available

Comment: The issue is that that is [not on the page when its first loaded](https://i.imgur.com/VwjA0uA.png), it is [added dynamically](https://i.imgur.com/EStUeEr.png) afterwards. You could still get it from that page by using something like [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html), but I think it'd be easier to pull the data from [this page](https://www.sportsexperts.ca/fr-CA/femmes/chaussures), as those prices are put into the page server-side.

Comment: So how would you write the code on that first page?

Answer (score 0):

All the prices (be it price after discount or the price that has no sale) are located inside the `<div class="product-tile-price">` tag. So, your job is to find those tags first and the use `.span.text` to get the price.

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
r = requests.get('https://www.sportsexperts.ca/fr-CA/femmes/chaussures')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

prices = [x.span.text for x in soup.find_all('div', class_='product-tile-price')]
print(prices)
```

Output:

```
['84,99 $', '67,49 $', '59,49 $', '48,99 $', '164,99 $', '77,99 $', '129,99 $', '94,99 $', '49,99 $', '49,99 $', '119,99 $', '89,99 $', '89,99 $', '74,99 $', '99,99 $', '149,99 $', '99,99 $', '159,99 $', '159,99 $', '99,99 $', '119,99 $', '139,99 $', '125,99 $', '84,99 $']
```

Comment: Thanks! How to now merge the brand and category with the price for each shoe so that when I export in a new .csv folder, all three elements are together, but in separate excel columns?

Comment: Since Im a new account, and already posted, it asks me to wait 2 days in order to ask another question... Can't you just help me out please?